When using listofitems to read a nested list to fill a table, \readlist seems to only read the last entry
I'm trying to construct a table, where the rows are provided by a nested list using package listofitems.
The idea is to have an empty macro (\itemRows), that iteratively gets expanded with individual entries of a (nested) list (\itemsTableContents), where ; is the outer delimiter, and , is the inner delimiter:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%-------------------[ functions to construct table ]

% empty macro to be extended by individual table rows
\newcommand{\itemRows}{}

% function to take a single nested table and iteratively extend the above macro with the table's contents
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemsTableContents}[1]{
    \setsepchar{;}
    \readlist*\itemlist{#1}
    \foreachitem \item \in \itemlist[]{
        \setsepchar{,}
        \readlist*\stats{\item}
        \g@addto@macro\itemRows{ \textbf{R} & \stats[1] & \stats[2] & \stats[3] & \stats[4] & \stats[5] \\ }
    }
}
\makeatother

% function to create the overall table, using the current state of the \itemRows macro
\newcommand{\itemsTable}[0]{
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
    & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
    \itemRows
    \end{tabular}
}

%---------------------------------------[ document ]

\begin{document}

    \itemsTableContents{
        Item A, 1, 2, 3, 4;
        Item B, 5, 6, 7, 8
    }

    \itemsTable{}

\end{document}

This almost works, except each row ends up being the same; specifically whichever row was parsed last:

Instead of the desired:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you add \show\itemRows at the end, you'll see
> \itemRows=macro:
-> \textbf {R} & \stats [1] & \stats [2] & \stats [3] & \stats [4] & \stats [5]
 \\  \textbf {R} & \stats [1] & \stats [2] & \stats [3] & \stats [4] & \stats [5] \\ .

and \stats is set to the last row. You need to expand \stats[<number>] before adding to \itemRows.
For instance with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%-------------------[ functions to construct table ]

% empty macro to be extended by individual table rows
\newcommand{\itemRows}{}

% function to take a single nested table and iteratively extend the above macro with the table's contents
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemsTableContents}[1]{
    \setsepchar{;}
    \readlist*\itemlist{#1}
    \foreachitem \item \in \itemlist[]{
        \setsepchar{,}
        \readlist*\stats{\item}
        \expanded{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\itemRows{
          \noexpand\textbf{R} & \stats[1] & \stats[2] & \stats[3] & \stats[4] & \stats[5]
           \noexpand\\ }
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

% function to create the overall table, using the current state of the \itemRows macro
\newcommand{\itemsTable}[0]{
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
    & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
    \itemRows
    \end{tabular}
}

%---------------------------------------[ document ]

\begin{document}

    \itemsTableContents{
        Item A, 1, 2, 3, 4;
        Item B, 5, 6, 7, 8
    }

\show\itemRows

    \itemsTable{}

\end{document}

You'd get
> \itemRows=macro:
-> \textbf {R} & Item A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\  \textbf {R} & Item B & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ .

and the output

This is very clumsy, isn't it?
With expl3. The idea is to split the input at semicolons. Then each item is processed by inserting at the beginning \textbf{R} & and also & between each (comma separated) item.
At the end the “out” sequence is delivered with \\ in between items.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemsTableContents}{m}
 {
  \fabian_items_toc:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemsTable}{}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
  & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l__fabian_items_rows_out_seq { \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__fabian_items_rows_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__fabian_items_rows_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabian_items_toc:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fabian_items_rows_in_seq { ; } {#1}
  \seq_set_map_e:NNn \l__fabian_items_rows_out_seq \l__fabian_items_rows_in_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n {\textbf{R}} & \clist_use:nn {##1} { & }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\itemsTableContents{
  Item A, 1, 2, 3, 4;
  Item B, 5, 6, 7, 8
}

\itemsTable

\end{document}

The output is the same as before.

This is great, thank you so much for taking the time to not only offer a solution within my own framework, but also demonstrate how it can be done in a different way! :)
